# Exception on Hosting.WebApp.Start()

Tags: exception, owin

I'm debugging a project where Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp class is used. This is a legacy code. At the same time the whole project is hosted inside IIS web application. When app pool is recycled, I'm receiving a massive exception eruption into the log file, and it says that "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

The line it points is no more than

```
App = WebApp.Start(url);
```

This problem occurs only on recycling. When I manually stop the pool and start it after a couple of seconds, it works well (until next recycle). I'm pretty sure the problem is that WebApp class is trying to register itself onto a port (defined by the url parameter) that is still registered after WebApp's previous instance (so that, for example, recycling without interruption of service is not possible).

Is there any way to check if port is already registered? To make it free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebApp class is from Microsoft.Owin.Hosting. You'd only use that when self-hosting. It does not make sense to have that in an web app running in IIS.

The way Owin/Katana starts when using IIS as a host is through a [**PreApplicationStartAttribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Using it, a Module is added that calls the Owin/Katana initialization code (finds Startup.cs, runs configuration, etc).
The dll that does this is Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.

(I have no reference for this, [I had to ask the source](https://twitter.com/DamianEdwards/status/499684349529186304))

In short, if you are running in IIS, you should use the Microsot.Owin.Host.SystemWeb nuget package. You should be able to remove that line: `App = WebApp.Start.`

Comment: Yes I agree it does not make much sense. But that program was a windows service earlier, and then I have to envelope it into a web-app while not making much changes on the code as 'who knows how exactly it works'. But I think I have a direction now.

Comment: That explains it then. If you use the conventions (your startup class is named Startup and has a `void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method) that change should be as easy as uninstalling `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.HttpListener` and installing `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.SystemWeb`

Comment: Now that I've changed hosting to SystemWeb, I'm running into another error. Application uses a class derived from PersistentConnection. So app.MapSignalR<MyConnection>("/path") is used. When I'm trying to connect to it with .NET SignalR client, I receive status code 500 in response. When I use just app.MapSignalR("/path"), I can connect, but, I assume, not to MyConnection. So probably there is some error inside it. I can't figure out - how to catch errors that are server-side (server started from VS in debug mode)? Breakpoints are all over the place already...

Comment: Oh, I've figured it out. You can set up VS to catch all exceptions in the Debug/Exceptions menu...